# How to call windows API in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

How to call windows API in NSIS?

Answer (score 4):

Use the system plugin, the basic syntax is: `System::Call 'windowsdll::function(parameters)'` Check the [docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/System/System.html) for details